# How do I pass W3 validation for Google checkout url?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, google-checkout

When I do validate the page in W3 validation, I got few errors with below code,

```
<input type="image" name="Google Checkout" alt="Fast checkout through Google"
src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/checkout.gif?merchant_id=xxxxxxxxx&w=168&h=44&style=white&variant=text&loc=en_US"  />
```

Errors are as follows,

> 1. cannot generate system identifier for general entity "w"
> 2. reference to entity "w" for which no system identifier could be generated
> 3. general entity "h" not defined and no default entity
> 4. reference to entity "h" for which no system identifier could be generated
> 5. general entity "style" not defined and no default entity
> 6. reference to entity "style" for which no system identifier could be generated
> 7. general entity "variant" not defined and no default entity
> 8. reference to entity "variant" for which no system identifier could be generated
> 9. general entity "loc" not defined and no default entity
> 10. reference to entity "loc" for which no system identifier could be generated

This is the only errors comes from the URL; is there way to pass W3 validation for this URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersands (`&`) to their HTML entity counterpart `&amp;`

New code:

```
<input type="image" name="Google Checkout" alt="Fast checkout through Google"
src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/checkout.gif?merchant_id=xxxxxxxxx&amp;w=168&amp;h=44&amp;style=white&amp;variant=text&amp;loc=en_US" />
```